# extracting time latitude and longitude from hexadecimal file

Tags: hexadecimal, gps

I am working on a GPS dump file. It contains the time as well as position data of a flying object. I am not sure in what units they are and there are no manuals available about the data format. I am giving sample data below.

```
-----------------------
0000 0000 6c00 0000 ff0f ec01 0000 0000
f004 400c 400c ff0f ff0f 0100 0100 0000
e00d 0100 0100 b001 ff0f 0000 0000 5703
0004 0000 ff0f 0100 ff0f 0000 0000 0400
0000 0000 0000 ff0f 0401 0001 ff0f ff0f
ff0f e800 0008 0100 0100 1400 0100 7402
5c02 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 8000 b80b
0000 ff0f ff0f 0000 ff0f 0100 0100 0000
0000 0000 6000 0000 ff0f 5c0e 0000 0000
--------
```

I believe each line has time as well as latitude-longitude-altitude information. Or instead of latitude-longitude-altitude it could be x,y,z earth fixed coordinate also. Not sure which one it is. Can anyone help in decoding? When I open this file in sublime it showed the format is hexadecimal.

Comment: Is this the whole file or an extract ? How long does this data represent a recording of ? Where in the world was the flying object when this was recorded (to the nearest degree or so) ?

Comment: Where did you acquire this from? Could be a custom datatype for geo data